# Is it possible to isolate domain.ext, sub1.domain.ext and sub2.domain.ext’s cookies from one another?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am developing a web app that is served from domain.ext. This web app uses cookie–based sessions and provides users with the ability to host a web pages containing custom JavaScript on a subdomain, ex. sub1.domain.ext, sub2.domain.ext. The subdomains do not use cookie–backed sessions.

Given this setup, is it possible to ensure the following?:

1. users at sub1.domain.ext cannot read or write a cookie for domain.ext (i.e. domain.ext sessions cannot be stolen or hijacked by JavaScript embedded in a page at sub1.domain.ext).
2. JavaScript embedded in a page at sub1.domain.ext cannot read or write cookies at sub2.domain.ext, and vice versa.

I’ve tested out a few things, for example it appears to be possible to interact with domain.ext’s cookies from sub1.domain.ext by running `document.domain = 'domain.ext'` inside the sub1.domain.ext’s window. Is there some way to prevent this, for example by specifying some kind of policy when setting the domain from domain.ext?

Comment: you can enforce your `domain.ext` to redirect to `www.domain.ext`. This should protect the cookies created there as it is treated as another subdomain.. (*untested*)

Comment: Thanks, Gaby. I think that’s what I’ll end up having to do, although I like to normalise all my URLs to the non–www variant (I think it’s ugly but that’s just my opinion).

Comment: i prefer the non-www too. But for this case you cant avoid it ..

Comment: I was afraid you might say that! Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify that a cookie should only be valid for `example.com` by setting the `domain` parameter. If you set `domain=example.com`, it will be valid for `*.example.com`.

Setting a cookie on `example.com` *without* a `domain` parameter sets a cookie for only `example.com` in most browsers. But not IE.

So, if you ever want to have subdomains with separate cookie contexts, you should serve your site from `www.example.com` *only*. As Gaby said, naturally you can still support access through `example.com` by giving a 301 redirect to the `www` version.

Comment: Thanks, bobince. I was thinking that we could serve the public–facing (cookie/session–less) site on domain.ext, with www.domain.ext 301–ing to domain.ext. We could then host the actual app on something like manage.domain.ext or panel.domain.ext.

Comment: Yes, if `domain.ext` never sets cookies the bare domain is OK. One thing to look out for, though: whilst `sub1.domain.ext` can't *read* cookies from `sub2.domain.ext`, it can *set* a cookie on `domain.ext` that will be read by `sub2.domain.ext` if `sub2` has not already set a more specific cookie.